# Trouble iterating through array to plot 20 images from data set using the array list as indexes

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot

```
rand20 = array([ 80, 337, 275, 651, 226, 
                681, 282, 958, 150, 790, 
                954, 929, 846, 848, 177, 
                165, 280, 196, 694, 159])
```

I am trying to plot images from xtrain using `plt.imshow(xtrain[rand20[i]])` where ideally i iterates through array rand20.

I need to also create a 5x4 subplot

```
plt.subplot(5,4,1) 
plt.imshow(xtrain[rand20[0]])
```

I'm stuck here and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `zip` here:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(5,4,1)

for idx, ax in zip(rand20, axes.ravel()):
    ax.imshow(xtrain[idx])
```